# Whats the difference between + and | when adding to another variable?

Tags: python

Considering the following

```py
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 5
```

What is the difference between adding the values to `c` using `+` or `|`?

```py
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
15
>>> c = a | b
>>> c
15
```

I ask this question based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168583/2483927) where binary and bitwise operations are used, if that makes any difference.

From the answer linked above:

> ```py
> >>> mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun = (pow(2, i) for i in range(7)) 
> >>> bin(mon) '0b1'
> >>> bin(sun) '0b1000000'
>
> # create range:
> >>> x = mon | wed | fri
> >>> bin(x) '0b10101'
>
> # check if day is in range:
> >>> x & mon
> 1
> >>> x & tue
> 0
> ```

Comment: In cases where `a` and `b` have no overlapping bits, nothing. `5` is `0101` and `10` is `1010`, so the bitwise or and numerical addition are equal; `15` is `1111`.

Comment: Try `10 | 6`, and you get `14`. It's only in special cases that these two have equal results.

Comment: For what reason would `|` be used? I couldn't find anything when searching for the `|` symbol. Or is it interchangeable with `+` in python?

Comment: You've just been given an example where `a + b != a | b`. Why would you think they are interchangeable?

Comment: @chepner it was coincidence that the example I used happened to result in 15 in each case which caused my confusion. I didn't see the 2nd comment but the answers cleared things up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to know the difference between + and | it is better to consider, in the beginning, identical values in the variables.

```
a = b = 5
print(a + b)
# result is 10
print(a | b)
# result is 5
```

so in the first, it is a normal addition operation, but in the second, it is a bit-wise `OR` operation.

5 in the binary system is `101`

so `a | b` = `101 or 101` = `101` = `5` in decimal

if we make `b = 2`, so `b = 10` in binary

So, `a | b` = `101 or 010` = `111` = `7` in decimal

Comment: This makes much sense. Really cleared things up. Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Well, one's an 'or' operation on the binary representation of the digits -- that's the "|" operator.

The other is +, which adds two numbers (integers in this case).

It just happens that the 'or' operation on 10 and 5 is:

5  =   00101

10=   01010

so the bitwise or gets you: 11111 which is 15

If you do 10 + 6, you get 16. However, 10 | 7 gets you binary `11111` which is 15 as well...
`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, was a coincidence that the result was 15 in both cases which added to my confusion